# Kotlin parse Hex String to Long

Tags: hex, kotlin, long-integer

I am starting to work in Kotlin and I need to parse a hex String to a long, which in java can be done with

```
Long.parseLong("ED05265A", 16);
```

I can not find anything this in Kotlin, although I can find

```
val i = "2".toLong()
```

This is not what I am looking for!

before I write anything from scratch is there a built in function for this?

Comment: How about `java.lang.Long.parseLong("ED05265A", 16)`? Or `import java.lang.Long.parseLong [...] parseLong("ED05265A", 16)`? Kotlin is compatible with Java, and you can, and should, use Java's built-in classes and methods.

Comment: will try it now

Comment: it works, answer the question and I will accept!

Comment: Note that you may want to use `Long.parseUnsignedLong` instead of `Long.parseLong`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can simply use

```
java.lang.Long.parseLong("ED05265A", 16)
```

Or

```
import java.lang.Long.parseLong 

[...] 

parseLong("ED05265A", 16)
```

Kotlin is compatible with Java, and you can, and should, use Java's built-in classes and methods.

Comment: When using Integer.parseInt("ffff0000", 16) , I get exception: NumberFormatException: For input string: "ffff0000" . How come?

Comment: It's larger than the max integer value.

Comment: But on Java it works fine, and is easy to read because in this case it's a representation of a color (red color in this case). Suppose I have an hexa-decimal value that I used fine in Java, what should I set its value in Kotlin? Do I really have to manually convert it myself?

Comment: No, it doesn't work in Java. You'd need to use parseUnsignedInt().

Comment: Correct. I thought it will also work (never needed to use it, so forgot it has this issue), because my use case is on something else. Please consider checking this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47001467/878126

Comment: "Kotlin is compatible with Java" is true only on JVM target, but not on Javascript or native targets. There you won't find any java.lang.Long.

Answer (score 68):

[Since](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/bc944961f1d56506b69c22c79ede0ac1311c30f5/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/text/StringNumberConversions.kt#L101) Kotlin v1.1 you can use:

```
"ED05265A".toLong(radix = 16)
```

Until then use the Java's `Long.parseLong`.