# How to use "setTextColor(hexaValue)" on Kotlin for Android,

Tags: android, textview, kotlin

### Background

In Java, I could directly change the text color of a TextView, using the standard hexa-decimal value of it:

```
    textView.setTextColor(0xffffffff); //white
    textView.setTextColor(0x00000000); //transparent
    textView.setTextColor(0xff000000); //black
    textView.setTextColor(0xff0000ff); //blue
    //etc...
```

Very easy...

### The problem

On Kotlin, if I try to write such a thing, I get with a weird build error:

> Error:(15, 18) None of the following functions can be called with the
>   arguments supplied: public open fun setTextColor(p0: ColorStateList!):
>   Unit defined in android.widget.TextView public open fun
>   setTextColor(p0: Int): Unit defined in android.widget.TextView

### What I've tried

I tried to search about this over the Internet, and I couldn't see anything special about hexa-decimal values. Seems the same like on Java:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html

Then I decided to just write in Java, and convert to Kotlin. The result is very unreadable in terms of the color value:

```
    textView.setTextColor(-0x1) //white
    textView.setTextColor(0x00000000) //transparent
    textView.setTextColor(-0x1000000) //black
    textView.setTextColor(-0xffff01) //blue
```

To me it seem that the hexadecimal value of Integer that is used for Kotlin is signed, while on Java it's converted to signed one automatically, so this causes flipping of values and the need to set a minus sign when needed.

The only thing I can think of, that still allows to read it well, is something like this:

```
textView.setTextColor(Integer.parseUnsignedInt("ffff0000",16));
```

However, this has multiple disadvantages:

1. It is way longer.
2. It converts a String, so it's much less efficient
3. Most importantly: it works only from API 26 (Android O) , which currently is active on about 1% of Android devices worldwide.

### The questions

Why does it occur?

What exactly can I do to make it the most readable, without string conversions, and work on all Android versions (minSdkVersion 14 in my case) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [0xFF0000FF An integer literal does not conform to the expected type kotlin.Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33023949/0xff0000ff-an-integer-literal-does-not-conform-to-the-expected-type-kotlin-int)

Comment: @JBNizet Is there a better way than to use "toInt()"  ? Maybe some kind of a keyword special for Kotlin ? What would you do in the case of long?

Comment: As far as as I know, no.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't actually call a function on this case, as it's constant?

Comment: Also, is there maybe a bitwise operation that's best to cover this case, as alternative to toInt() ?

Comment: Use [color resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#color-element).

Comment: @ephemient Both ways are legit. I'm asking about this one.

Comment: Yeah, basically the issue is that a hex value is actually a 64bit int, but this method expects a 32bit int to be passed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for putting something on such an old question, but an extension function really seemed like the nicest approach:

```
fun TextView.setTextColor(color: Long) = this.setTextColor(color.toInt())
```

now, you can just go `textView.setTextColor(0xff00ff00)` again

Answer (score 18):

```
textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0aad3f"))
```

Comment: Maybe it's possible to have an extension function, that I give it the value as on Java, and it will convert it to the real value it's supposed to be?

Answer (score 6):

`Oxff000000` is resolved to Long in Kotlin so right now there is no way to use this literal as is, however `0xff000000.toInt()` will give you exactly the same result as `-0x1000000` so you can use `.toInt()` approach. 
Under the hood, it's the equivalent of `(int)4278190080L` Java cast.

Also, with Kotlin extensions you can write a simple property like that

```
var TextView.textColor: Long
get() {
    //... not important
}
set(value: Long) {
    this.setTextColor(value.toInt())
}
```

and you'll be able to use a more concise syntax `textView.textColor = 0xff000000`

**UPDATE**:
As of Kotlin 1.3 it will be possible to use concise syntax like that `0xff000000u`
See: [Jetbrains blog](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2018/08/kotlin-1-3-m2) and the [original proposal](http://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/unsigned-types.md)

Comment: Nice. What if I want the hexa-value of a long, though? Meaning something like this: 0xff000000ff000000 ? For this, it won't work to use "toLong", right?

Comment: @androiddeveloper that will not work, right. There is no type bigger that long to cast down, so in that case, you should explicitly make it negative like that `-0x7f000000ff000000`

Comment: Too bad it's in this ugly form. hex numbers should be without a sign...

Comment: Maybe it's possible to have an extension function, that I give it the value as on Java, and it will convert it to the real value it's supposed to be?

Comment: @android-developer that's exactly what this property does it takes a value in the familiar format and converts it to int.
You can convert setter into a function

    fun TextView.setTextColor(color: Long) {
       this.setTextColor(color.toInt())
    }

and use it a function

Comment: Oops I meant annotation. Is it possible to somehow have an annotation that will deal with it instead, so that in build time it will be converted to the proper value?

Comment: @android-developer technically it's possible but that will require an extra code-generation step that will parse the annotation and convert the value so it will end up with the same code. AFAIK No ready-to-use annotation for that purpose exists right now. However, Kotlin team is releasing v1.3 soon that should support unsigned integers out of the box (including hex literals).
See: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2018/08/kotlin-1-3-m2/ and 
https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/unsigned-types.md

Comment: What I suggested is maybe have the calculation in build time, so it's not the same as "toInt()".

Comment: Can you please update your answer to include the future way of how to use it? Currently I will give you +1, and when it's finally out, I will accept the answer.

Comment: So you mean `textView.setTextColor(0xff000000u) ` , because I think `0xff0000u`  might be a different color.

Comment: @android-developer Sorry, yep. Updated the answer.

Comment: Today we use `1.3.50` version of Kotlin, and I still don't see "u" as something the IDE offers or allows. For example: `ColorDrawable(0xfff2f2f2u)` isn't allowed, but `ColorDrawable(0xfff2f2f2u.toInt())` is allowed. How come?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/878126/android-developer even though UInt type is now supported IDE, Android Library doesn't accept this type yet `ColorDrawable` constructor only accepts int value, so explicit conversion is still required, unfortunately. Don't know if Android team is going to add UInt support. So the initial proposal is still valid: custom extension that supports either Long or UInt would do the job.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/878126/android-developer yep, "u" works and you can define the extension that takes UInt parameter like `textView.setTextColor(0xff000000u)` at least that will be less ambiguous than switching b/w original method and extension that takes Long.

Answer (score 6):

for changing the text color, you can follow this -

```
textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext,R.color.colorAccent))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try this to set color of your text programmatically.

```
textview.textColor=Color.parseColor("#22aadd")
```

Comment: Works, but still, it calls a function instead of just using the value as it is, at compile time

Answer (score 2):

```
textview.setTextColor("#ffffff".toColor())
```

toColor() in an extension function defined below.

```
fun String.toColor(): Int = Color.parseColor(this)
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid using extra functions