# hexString.toInt(32) NumberFormatException

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a 32-bit hex value that I wish to convert to an integer.

The following methods both provide the following error given the hex string `C71C5E00`:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "C71C5E00"

```
"C71C5E00".toInt(32)
Integer.valueOf("C71C5E00", 32)
```

The Kotlin [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/index.html) state that an Int *Represents a 32-bit signed integer*, so it's not that the value is too large to pack into an Int. I've tried, in vain, prepending `0x` to the string.

**EDIT:** As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41651704/kotlin-parse-hex-string-to-long) question I've attempted:

```
java.lang.Integer.parseInt("C71C5E00", 32)
```

Unfortunately, I am still receiving the same error.

I don't often touch Android or Kotlin so forgive my ignorance.

Comment: Same error with `java.lang.Integer.parseInt`, will update question to reflect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, you seem to have misunderstood the radix, which is the second argument in `valueOf` and `parseInt`, and the only argument with the extension function `toInt`. It doesn't represent the bits in the target number type, it tells the method how to convert your string by informing it of what [base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix) it's operating in. Note that there is a second problem, which I will get back to later.

Radix is the base number of the underlying number system. By default it's 10 (the 0-arg `toInt()` method. `toInt()` calls `parseInt`, which looks like this:

> ```
> public static int parseInt(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
>     return parseInt(s,10);
> }
> ```

As you see, it uses radix = 10. Again, the bits of the number type isn't relevant here. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix#In_numeral_systems) covers it pretty well, and Java follows more or less the same system. As you see, 16 corresponds to hex. So the appropriate radix to use here is 16.

**However,** like I mentioned, there's a second problem. It will still crash, because the value can't be parsed. The resulting number is `3340525056`, which is more than the max int value, which is 2147483647.

Which means, you can't use any of the int methods; you'll need to use `Long` ones.

So, for your case, this is fine:

```
val x = "C71C5E00".toLong(16)
```

Again, the radix is the number system to use, not the amount of bits in the resulting number. If it was, you'd need to use 64 for longs.

Bonus: ints and longs have a pre-determined amount of bits. By using `toInt()`, you're already implicitly requesting 32 bits. with a Long, you're requesting 64 bits.

Comment: Short answer val x = "C71C5E00".toLong(16) :)